# Conditional BasedOn in XAML styles

Tags: wpf, xaml

Given:

```
<Style x:Key="ThirdLevelGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush3}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SecondLevelGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush2}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="GroupBox" x:Key="WidgetControlTemplateStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ThirdLevelGroupBoxStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanExecuteClickCommand}" Value="True">
            <!-- TODO: SecondLevelGroupBoxStyle -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="WidgetControlTemplate">
    <GroupBox ... Style="{StaticResource WidgetControlTemplateStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </GroupBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

`ControlTemplate` has style `WidgetControlTemplate`. I want to base (`BasedOn`) the `WidgetControlTemplate` style conditionally on `ThirdLevelGroupBoxStyle` or `SecondLevelGroupBoxStyle`, in order to avoid XAML duplication. Is there way to achieve this?

If I can't do that, I have to duplicate the definition of `SecondLevelGroupBoxStyle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there way to achieve this?

No, not in XAML. The base style to base the style on must be known at design-time.

> If I can't do that, I have to duplicate the definition of SecondLevelGroupBoxStyle.

Since you have two different styles that are based on MetroGroupBox, each style that is based on either of this will always be a separate style because you cannot base a single style on more than one style.

What you could do is to use a trigger that sets the Background property of the GroupBox to either AccentColorBrush3 or AccentColorBrush2 instead of trying to inherit this property from another style. It seems like you are already doing this in your WidgetControlTemplateStyle style. And yes, if the ThirdLevelGroupBoxStyle/SecondLevelGroupBoxStyle sets more than one property you will have to set all these in the WidgetControlTemplateStyle as well.

I am afraid there is no way around this unless you merge your two style into one or define them programatically somehow.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know there is no good way to do it. And yes, it's more than 1 property ;(